# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'control-bus'

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using spring 5.2.5 version. I added the below lines to my file and I got this error.

```
<integration:channel id="controlChannel"/>
<integration:control-bus input-channel="controlChannel"/>
```

The declaration is as below:

```
          <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
      xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx/spring-integration-jmx.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">
```

The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'control-bus'

Please help.

Comment: What is your `xmlns` and `schemaLocation` definition? Show, please, the whole XML config including root `<beans>` element.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the declaration.